# refactor a dal with hibernate,dao,services and unit of work : how to put all togheter

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns, refactoring

i'm refactoring a jsf web application dal which uses hibernate and the dao pattern, at the moment each data acces class handles its own session and transaction into each method (a session per operation antipattern is it? )
for example :

```
public void saveEntity(ModelEntity entity) throws Exception {
    String entityName = getCleanClassName(entity.getClass());
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        session = SessionFactoryUtil.getInstance().openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
        session.flush();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        tx.rollback();
                    ...
        throw new Exception(msg, ex);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Above classes can be used directly into backing bean actions or through some business logic classes methods (for example create new detached object, set some values and store them trhough DAO objects). Now i've found that some businness logic classes methods need to be executed atomically, for example :

```
                       //inside some backing bean actionlistener
        DocumentoManager dm = new DocumentoManager();
        PraticaManager pm = new PraticaManager();
        Documento newDoc = new Documento();
        newDoc.setDataArrivo(new java.util.Date                           newDoc.setNote("...");
        Allegato newAll = new Allegato();
        newAll.setTitolo(newDoc.getNote());
                       //businness logic methods that should be executed atomically
        dm.creaDocumentoDaAllegato(newDoc,newAll,
            event.getFile().getContents(),
            event.getFile().getFileName(),
            "");
        pm.collegaDocumento(pratica, newDoc);
```

Finally i've a sessionFactoryUtil class which manages hibernate session (getcurrentSession, openSession, etc ... ).

How can i refactor the above architecture? i was thinking to do the following:

1. remove the transaction from the DAO objects : i can't put
   transactions management into bl classes (xxxManager) , so should i
   use a class that just create,commit or rollback the transaction ,
   encapsulating the sessionFactoryUtil, and to be used inside backing
   beans (say jta userTransaction) ?
2. If someone try to use directly the DAO object how do i set the session ? Accessing sessionFactoryUtil into DAOs methods ?
3. Is it safe to call getCurrentSession inside DAOs?
4. if i create a class to handle businness logic transactions, how can i be sure it's thread safe ?

I think sessionFactoryUtil is thread safe since it's been written following the pattern suggested on hibernate guide :

```
private SessionFactoryUtil() {
}

static {
    // Annotation and XML
    // sessionFactory = new
    // AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    // XML only
    try {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
                  ...
    }

}

public static SessionFactory getInstance() {
    try{
        return sessionFactory;
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Transactions should not be part of the DAO.  Those should be handled by a service layer that manages DAOs, model objects, and transactions to fulfill use cases.  The service layer owns and manages the unit of work.

DAOs should be about persistence only.  They need not know anything about sessions.  Let the service give the DAO what it needs to persist an object.

Comment: @ duffymo that's exactly what i'd like to accomplish and what i need to be adviced on how to proceed from actual scenario